# Finding the column index where a row changes values in R dataframe/Datatable

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(Col1=c(2,2,1),Col2=c(2,7,5),Col3=c(9,6,4))
```

I would like to know 2 things:

- how can I get another field stating the index of the column where that row changes values. Hence, for the first row we'd get 1 and 3, and for the second and third rows, 1, 2 and 3.
- How to get a field of the "before and after"? for the first case, something like 2 -> 9, for the second and third, 2->7, 7-> 6 and 1 ->5, 5->4, respectively.

Comment: If you're looking for the index of the column where the row changes values, wouldn't you want 2 and 3 for the first row, since between 1 and 2 the value isn't changing?

Comment: Yes. It's the same for all practical purposes, as the value is the same, but from 2 to 3 may be easier to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
x <- sapply(1:NCOL(df), function(x) rle(df[x,])$values)
```

Output of x:

```
[[1]]
  Col2 Col3
1    2    9

[[2]]
  Col1 Col2 Col3
2    2    7    6

[[3]]
  Col1 Col2 Col3
3    1    5    4
```

Then if you'd like the full range of before/after values, you could use:

```
lapply(x,function(i) paste0(i,collapse="->"))

[[1]]
[1] "2->9"

[[2]]
[1] "2->7->6"

[[3]]
[1] "1->5->4"
```

Comment: Great :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(X = DF, MARGIN = 1, function(x) cumsum(rle(x)$lengths))
#[[1]]
#Col1 Col3 
#   2    3 

#[[2]]
#Col1 Col2 Col3 
#   1    2    3 

#[[3]]
#Col1 Col2 Col3 
#   1    2    3 

apply(X = DF, MARGIN = 1, function(x){
    temp = unique(x)
        if (length(temp) == 1){
            temp
        }else{
            sapply(1:(length(temp)-1), function(i)
                paste(temp[i:min(i+1, length(temp))], collapse = ">"))
        }
    })
#[[1]]
#[1] "2>9"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2>7" "7>6"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1>5" "5>4"
```

Comment: @Arrebimbomalho since this answer seemed to help you, consider accepting it (check mark to the left). This lets the community know it worked for your case.